# IN condition is not working when the data is like 'Test','Test' from a result query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In one table I have a data like 'Test1','Test2' for one column. Why I can not use this column data in one more select query with IN condition.

```
Example:

Table TESTING2:

AREA_NAME
-------------------------------
'Tilaknagar','Kadubeesinahalli'

Table TESTING1:

NAME    AREA
----    ----------------
Ravi    Tilaknagar
Ram     Kadubeesinahalli
```

If I write query

```
SELECT *
FROM TESTING1
WHERE AREA IN (SELECT AREA_NAME FROM TESTING2);
```

is not working. How to make this one to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `replace` function to replace `'` comma then `regexp_substr` to split comma.

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING2(
   AREA_NAME VARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO TESTING2 VALUES ('''Tilaknagar'',''Kadubeesinahalli''');


CREATE TABLE TESTING1(
   NAME VARCHAR(50),
   AREA VARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO TESTING1 VALUES ('Ravi','Tilaknagar');
INSERT INTO TESTING1 VALUES ('Ram','Kadubeesinahalli');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TESTING1 
WHERE AREA IN (
    SELECT regexp_substr(replace(AREA_NAME,'''','') , '[^,]+', 1, x.n)
    FROM TESTING2 
    cross join (SELECT ROWNUM n FROM dual CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5) x
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1753e/1/0)**:

```
| NAME |             AREA |
|------|------------------|
| Ravi |       Tilaknagar |
|  Ram | Kadubeesinahalli |
```

**NOTE**

`CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5` the number need to set greater than `AREA_NAME` column comma amount.

Comment: You can use `REGEXP_COUNT` instead of relying on `ROWNUM <= 5`

Answer (score 1):

It is a very bad table design. You should consider changing it and normalize the table. Storing comma separated values are bound to cause problems.

You could do something like this. This may be  slightly efficient than Regexp solutions.

```
SELECT *
FROM testing1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM testing2 t2
     WHERE ',' || t2.area_name || ',' LIKE '%,''' || t1.area || ''',%'
);
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=300bd6dc26fbee5ae1df9d4b3609754c)

Answer (score 0):

An "IN" clause can be used to pull data from one table and use it to filter a driving table. The value from both tables on the columns used must match EXACTLY (case, order, etc.). If they don't match, no rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out this is a very bad design. But a simpler query also solves the request. Hope your tables are not large.

```
select distinct t1.* 
  from testing1 t1
     , testing2 t2
 where instr(t2.area_name,t1.area) > 0;
```